# Give Script Reference to AjaxControlToolKitScriptManager from Static Server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm keeping the referenced files in a bundle on a static server and want to reference to the AjaxControlToolKitScriptManager for scriptreference . It is not working .  Is there any other way out?.  Below is the code  which I'm trying to implement. Browser is able to download file But telerik controls are not able to access it

```
public void IncludeBundleFiles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/JavaScript/TelerikListMaster").Include(
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/Core.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/Ajax.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/jQuery.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/jQueryPlugins.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadGridScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/GridCellSelection.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/OverlayScript.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/NavigationScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/AnimationScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadComboBoxScripts.js",
               "~/JavaScript/Telerik/TouchScrollExtender.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadMenuScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadContextMenuScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadFilterScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadMenuItem.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadAutoCompleteBoxScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/PopUpScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadToolTipScripts.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadToolTipManager.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadInputScript.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadNumericInputScript.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadCalendarCommonScript.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadCalendarScript.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadDatePicker.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadPickersPopupDirectionEnumeration.js",
            "~/JavaScript/Telerik/RadInputManagerScript.js"));
}

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="true" ScriptMode="Release">
            <CompositeScript Path="https://localhost/JavaScript/TelerikListMaster">
                <Scripts>

                </Scripts>
            </CompositeScript>
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to Place the references of scripts to get from Static server under composite tag and place the combine script of all the scripts on Static server. Please refer to this article for further information.[here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx)

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"     CombineScripts="true" ScriptMode="Release">
        <CompositeScript Path="https://localhost/StaticServer/JavaScript/TelerikListMaster.js">
            <Scripts>
                  <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Common/Core.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/TextBox/RadInputScript.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/NumericTextBox/RadNumericInputScript.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Common/jQuery.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Navigation/OData.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Common/jQueryPlugins.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Common/TouchScrollExtender.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Navigation/OverlayScript.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Navigation/NavigationScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/ComboBox/RadComboBoxScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/ComboBox/View/ClassicView.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/RadGrid/RadGridScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Calendar/RadDatePicker.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Calendar/RadPickersPopupDirectionEnumeration.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/DateInput/RadDateInputScript.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Common/Scrolling/ScrollingScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Animation/AnimationScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Menu/RadMenuScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Menu/ContextMenu/RadContextMenuScripts.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Menu/MenuItem/RadMenuItem.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Menu/View/ClassicView.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Calendar/RadCalendarScript.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Telerik/Calendar/RadCalendarCommonScript.js" ScriptMode="Release" />
            </Scripts>
        </CompositeScript>
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```